# InDesign cc 2015 - Right to Left

Tags: adobe-indesign

Im totally new to InDesign and struggling a lot with it whenever I try to use Arabic...
So I figured how to make arabic work but still I can't find a way how to change the writing direction from `Left to Right` to `Right to Left`
If I wanna write arabic with numbers I get this results
The numbers always end at the end of the sentence.

> 300 غرام سميد ناع

So how I can change the writing direction so I can get the numbers at any position I want without messing up the sentence ?

InDesign CC 2015

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to install arabic version. See [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/kb/access-install-hebrew-arabic-indesign-illustrator-CC.html) how.
Then, use the Paragraph panel to select Right to Left feature:
[image]

Or use a character style to specify direction within paragraph. More info [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/arabic-hebrew.html).